# Set builder notation for time at which a stationary equilibrium is reached?

Tags: notation

I have a system of equations that entails damped oscillations (i.e., the system oscillates deterministically until reaching a stationary point). Using set notation, how would I represent the time at which the stationary point is reached (i.e., after the damped oscillations have occurred)?

Thank you,

Alex

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you could provide some more details, both about the problem and about what kind of answer you are looking for. For example: a) What kind of system of equations is it? (System of ODE/PDEs? Discrete dynamical system? Something else?) b) What, more specifically, do you mean by "represent the time..."? It may be best if you give a concrete example of the kind of system you are looking at, to help the reader understand what you are after.

Comment: A set builder notation for that will probably be longer and more obscure than the clear English phrase "time at which a stationary equilibrium is reached".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One challenge because you do not state that your system variables are continuous, differentiable, or continuously differentiable, is that the system may be in the stationary state on an open set of times, $(a,\infty)$.  On the other hand, if your system is continuous, then the set of times the system is in a *single* distinguished stationary state is a closed set of times.  In the latter case, the infimum of the set of times the system is in the stationary state until the end of time is the time you want.

Let $X$ represent the dependent variables in your system and let time, the independent variable, be a real number.  One way to get the time you want (assuming it exists) is

$$\inf \{s : \forall t > s, X(t) = \lim_{u \rightarrow \infty} X(u) \}  \text{.}$$

If you don't want to take an infimum,
$$\{s : \forall t > s, X(t) = \lim_{u \rightarrow \infty} X(u)\} \cap \{s : \forall t < s, X(t) \neq \lim_{u \rightarrow \infty} X(u)\}  $$

If there eventually is a stationary state, it will be reached by the end of time, then we can back up to the earliest time it was forever after in that state.  Note that the infimum can fail to exist or the intersection of sets can be empty if the system only asymptotically approaches a stationary state or never settles into a stationary state.